# mysql copy data from table to table 2 without duplicate the data and add new rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables :

table1 - IP,SN,version,date,working

table2 - IP,SN,Vesrion

I want to add to table2 only the IPs that aren't in the table already from table1. And update the SN+version according to table1 (just the new  lines I added)

I found here how to do the update according to IP from another table 
but I didn't find how to add it without duplicate.

This is what I want to do:

```
table 1 
IP
10.0.0.5
10.0.0.6
10.0.0.7

table2 
IP 
10.0.0.5
192.168.30.11
1.1.1.1
```

So in the end of the function table1 will not change 
and table2 will be :

```
IP
10.0.0.5
192.168.30.11
1.1.1.1
10.0.0.6
10.0.0.7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two separate queries to do this job.

1. Add records in table 2 which are not present

   ```
   INSERT INTO table2 (SELECT IP, SN, Vesrion FROM table1 where table1.IPnot in (select IPfrom table2));
   ```
2. Update existing data

   ```
   UPDATE TABLE table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.IP = table1.IP SET table2.SN = table1.SN, table2.vesion = table1.version WHERE table1.version <> table2.version OR table2.SN <> table1.SN
   ```

Comment: didn't work - nothing is added :-(   what could be wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide me a data and schema of table1 & 2?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NOT EXISTS` to exclude rows with `IP` already being in `table1`.

```
INSERT INTO table1
            (IP)
            SELECT t1.ROU_IP
                   FROM routers t1
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM table1 t2
                                            WHERE t2.IP = t1.ROU_IP);
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I got lost  ,   can you show mw with my own row names? Thanks ,

Comment: @Korenron: Rows don't have names. Maybe you mean columns? But I used the names from your OP. So what do you mean?

Comment: sorry - colomns . And if you can look down at my answer - there I wrote the real names of everything.. the first post was general  :-)

Comment: @Korenron: Aha, yes... Don't do that. If you want to add or change anything edit your question. Only post an answer if it really is an answer, like, when you've found a solution by yourself. Also consider showing exactly what you have in the question form the beginning on. Otherwise it's totally confusing. Please edit your question and delete that answer. Anyway, see my edit...

Comment: ohh - didn't know it...... it's working so thank you :-)   and just to understand - t1&t2 are tmp variables right?

Comment: @Korenron: Nope, they're aliases. You can have an alias for a table in a query. Sometimes this makes things more readable, sometimes it's necessary when the same table occurs twice in a query with different "roles", to distinguish between these "roles".